# Is it possible to make an input field with non selectable text in Unity?

Tags: unity, input, text

Can I make an input field with non selectable text in Unity?

Answer (score 1):

You can make InputFields non selectable by setting enabled to false.

```
inputfield.enabled = false;
```

This will disable input though.

Use the API documentation to experiment with the input field:
https://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html

Comment: I meant the text in the input field, if you select the text the background will become blue.

Comment: Yes, disabling the input stops you being able to select text. Keeping text navigation and input functionality will always have the blue effect on that control.